# SeekBar change gray color

Tags: android, xml, android-seekbar

I searched a lot but could not find.

I want the basic gray color of `SeekBar` change to white.
All the examples I've found it just change the color of progress.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating progress.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background" 
          android:drawable="@drawable/background_fill" />

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip android:drawable="@drawable/progress_fill" />
    </item>
```

Then in your seekbar declaration in xml set:

```
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below link for creating Android components such as editext or spinner or seekbar with your own colors for your Android application. It will generate all necessary nine patch assets plus associated XML drawables and styles which you can copy straight into your project.

For ex. for your case you can go to this link and download the zip file for your new seekbar with custom color.

http://android-holo-colors.com

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
    android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/gray"
    android:progressTint="@color/white"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So, there are two things

- You want to change `Seekbar` style through out the app
- You want to change `Seekbar` style for specific screen

1. If want to change through out the app. Add this in your `style.xml`

```xml
<resources>
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
      
       <item name="seekBarStyle">@style/AppSeekBar</item>
   </style>

   <style name"AppSeekBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar">
       <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
       <item name="android:background">@drawable/app_seekbar_background</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

And that's it, all `SeekBar` in the app will start using this style.

2. If you want to change for specific screen. Add this in your `style.xml`

```xml
<resources>
   <!-- your rest of code -->

   <style name"AppSeekBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar">
       <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
       <item name="android:background">@drawable/app_seekbar_background</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

And in the `your_layout.xml` file add this

```xml
<!-- your rest of code for layout -->
<SeekBar
   android:layout_width="100dp"
   android:layout_height="40dp"
   style="@style/AppSeekBar"
   <!-- your rest of code for seek bar-->
/>
```

This should reflect your style.

And if you want to change anything else for you can come to this `style.xml` file and change, no need to change each and places you are using `SeekBar`